# Is there a way to escape the C string null terminator character?

Tags: c

I have a simple question that I couldn't find the answer for by googling -- is it possible to escape the C language's string null terminator '\0', so that we can include it in a string?

Comment: Just like you did, `"two\0strings"`.  There are some api functions that require such a string, avoiding an array, programmers very often fumble them.  If replacing an array is the intention then you need a final `\0` as well so you can see the array end with two zeros.

Comment: The two answers so far are reasonable answers to _two_ different interpretations of your question.  You need to clarify the ambiguity.  Do you want a character array containing NUL other than at the end (which is then not a string - by definition) or did you just want a literal `\` immediately followed by a '0' character?

Comment: @Clifford I meant the former question, and its been helpfully answered. Thanks.

Comment: You can do it [as in java](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8#Modified_UTF-8) using the `\xc0\x80` overlong utf-8 encoding.

Comment: See also [Why can a null character be embedded in a conversion specifier for scanf?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66013007/why-can-a-null-character-be-embedded-in-a-conversion-specifier-for-scanf)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note that a "string" with an embedded NUL is no longer a *string*. You cannot safely use it as an argument to functions declared in `<string.h>`, for example

```
char embeddednul[] = "zero\0one\0two\0"; // embeddednul[12] = embeddednul[13] = 0
printf("len: %d\n", strlen(embeddednul)); // 4??
char tmp[1000] = {0};
strcpy(tmp, embeddednul); // copies 'z', 'e', 'r', 'o', and 0

char *p = embeddednul;
while (*p) {
    while (*p) putchar(*p++); // prints zero
    putchar('\n');            // then   one
    p++;                      // then   two
}
```

Comment: I would not say that a string with an embedded NUL is "no longer a string".  Nor is there anything unsafe about passing it to a function that expects a string.  That function (any such function) will merely treat that embedded NUL as the (premature) end of the string.

Answer (score 2):

Use the \ to escape the \ like so

```
printf("\\0");
```

Answer (score 1):

You can *embed* a null character in a string.
But there is no way to *escape* the null character.

To "escape" something means to remove its usual or its special interpretation, or to give it some other interpretation.

In C string and character constants, the backslash character `\` gives a special meaning to the character following it.  For example, `n` is normally an ordinary letter, but `\n` is the newline character.  `0` is normally an ordinary digit character, but `\0` is the character with the numeric value 0, and is the NUL or end-of-string character.

So if you write something like

```
char *twostrings = "two\0strings";
```

you successfully embed a null character into the string.  But you haven't "escaped the null character" — you have in fact escaped the *zero*, to *turn it into* a null character.

Now, what if you wanted to "escape the null character" — that is, to remove its special meaning as the end-of string terminator?  And the answer is, no, there is no way to do that.  A null character is *always* treated as the end of a string, by any normal C function that deals with strings.  Given the `twostrings` variable initialized as above, if you write

```
printf("%zu\n", strlen(twostrings));
```

you're going to get 3, because `strlen` stops at the first null character it finds.  If you write

```
char onestring[10];
strcpy(onestring, twostrings);
printf("%s\n", onestring);
```

you're going to get "one", because `strcpy` stops at the first null character it finds.  You'll get the same thing if you write

```
printf("%s\n", twostrings);
```

If you tried to "escape the null character" by writing

```
twostrings = "two\\0strings";
```

what would actually happen is that you would *escape the backslash*, removing *its* special meaning.  You'd get an actual backslash character and an actual `0` character in the string, with no extra null character at all.

See also [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65907742/how-to-not-null-terminate-a-buffer).  See also [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66013007/why-can-a-null-character-be-embedded-in-a-conversion-specifier-for-scanf) and particularly the second part of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66013007/why-can-a-null-character-be-embedded-in-a-conversion-specifier-for-scanf/66013236#66013236).