# how to not null terminate a buffer?

Tags: c, substring, c-strings

Basically I want to know if there is a way to keep a null byte in a buffer?

Example:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    char buf[] = "hello there\x00, Hi";
    printf("%s\n", buf);

    return 0;
}
```

Unfortunately, if you compile above, the output you would get is `hello there` only (null terminated by `\x00`). So is there there a way to keep the null byte in the stack and get the `Hi` after that too?

FYI, if you wanted to recommend to escape `\` with `\\x00`, I can't do that.

Comment: Empedding the 0 in the array of bytes is tricky if you will treat it as a string. Can you please explain why you want this? It sounds like you actually want something else.

Comment: Since the `%s` stops processing at the first null byte, there's no way to do it with a simple (single) call to `printf()`.  What would you want in the output?  You could use `fwrite(buff, sizeof(buff) - 1, 1, stdout);` to write the null byte too (followed by `putchar('\n');` to output the newline).

Comment: The ", Hi" is also on the stack (in `buf`). It's just not printed. A C-style string can't contain a '\0', since that's the sentinel value it uses to determine the end of the string.

Comment: More or less a duplicate of [Is there a way to escape the C string null terminator character?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57834935).

Answer (score 3):

C strings by definition cannot incorporate NUL bytes, that is explicitly reserved as a terminating character. If you need a raw buffer that does support that then you can't use a C string. You will need to treat it differently. All of the C string functions starting with `str` are off-limits here.

`printf` with `%s` will of course terminate on the NUL byte. If you want to print the whole buffer then you need to use lower-level tools like `fwrite`.

Answer (score 2):

When you say

```
char buf[] = "hello there\x00, Hi";
```

the null byte and the "Hi" after them definitely *are* "in there".  The problem is merely that `printf` doesn't print them, because `printf` always stops when it sees the first null byte.  Most other standard string-handling functions will have the same problem.

You can work with strings containing null bytes if you want, but you will have to figure out your own way of keeping track of how long the string is, or where its end is, if not at the first null byte.

The usual way of dealing with "strings" of text that might contain null bytes is to use a second, separate character count variable.  (This is how the standard `fwrite` function works, for example.)  Alternatively (albeit rather nonstandardly), I have written code that detects and skips over embedded null bytes, and decides it's only *really* at the end of the string when it finds a pair of back-to-back null bytes.

And, no, you're right, there's no way to "escape" the null byte.  It may be instructive to explain why there isn't a way, and indeed why there can't possibly be.  "Under the covers", so to speak, the "null byte" is simply a byte with a value of 0.  It's what all the standard C string-handling functions are looking for to determine the end of the string, and there's no way to tell any of them to use some other interpretation, to somehow ignore a hypothetically "escaped" null byte and only stop at a "real" null byte.  As far as C string termination is concerned, a null byte is a null byte is a null byte.

In fact, when you write `"\0"` or `"\x00"`, you're already escaping things.  If you wrote `"0"` you'd get a length-1 string containing the character `'0'` (hex `0x30`), and if you wrote `"x00"` you'd get a length-3 string containing `x 0 0`.  It's only that backslash that turns either of these strings into one containing a literal null character.  If you tried to "escape" the null character, perhaps by writing `"\\0"` or `"\\x00"`, what would happen would be that you'd escape the backslash, which would take away its special meaning, meaning that it wouldn't help create a real null character, and instead you'd end up with a string containing either the two characters `\ 0` or the four characters `\ x 0 0`.

Answer (score 0):

If you know the actual size of the string with embedded zero characters or you know the number of substrings separated by the zero characters stored in a buffer then you can output it in parts.

For example

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main( void )
{
    char buf[] = "hello there\x00, Hi";
    printf("%s", buf);

    size_t n = strlen( buf );
    
    if ( n < sizeof( buf ) - 1 ) puts( buf + n + 1 ); 
    
    return 0;
}
```

The program output is

```
hello there, Hi
```

Comment: This seems like a gigantic hack that works if and only if that has one NUL byte, no more.

Comment: @tadman There is neither hack. It is enough to know the total length of the whole string with embedded zero characters or a number of substrings.

Comment: If this had a loop around it so it'd keep going until the whole buffer was written I'd at least be able to see how it's *technically* a valid solution, but as it stands it won't work in any case with > 1 NUL byte.

Comment: @tadman As I wrote the necessary condition is either you know the total length of the whole string or the number of substrings stored in the buffer. It is not a rare case when a buffer contains several strings.

Comment: ...or you could just use `fwrite`.